# Timer do not restart after being stop once

Tags: vb.net, timer

I am sending data through a COM port and starting my timer with a 4000 interval to send my message back if I did not receive anything before the 4 seconds.

{Load}

```
Private Sub MainForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    [...]    
    SendCard(0)
    [...]
End Sub
```

{SendCard Sub}
I'm sending the require information through this Sub by setting the property "LastCommand" which sends the data through the port.

```
Private Sub SendCard(ByVal cardIndex As Integer)
    If cardIndex < Setting.Machine.Cards.Length Then

        'Calling LastCommand's Set()
        LastCommand = "*" & Setting.Machine.Cards(cardIndex) & ": STRQ" & ControlChars.CrLf
    Else
        'Blah blah...
    End If

End Sub
```

The property sends the data and start the Timer.

```
Public Property LastCommand() As String
    Get
        Return lastCommandString
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        lastCommandString = value
        MainCOMSerialPort.Write(value)
        ResponseTimer.Start()
    End Set
End Property
```

When I receive an answer I stop the timer and then ask the information for the next card.

```
Private Sub MainCOMSerialPort_DataReceived(...)
   [...]
   ResponseTimer.Stop() 'After this stop it does not trigger the Tick event any longer.
   SendCard(Array.IndexOf(Setting.Machine.Cards, CardString) + 1) 'Sending the next card
   [...]
End Sub
```

The tick event works fine for the first card

```
Private Sub ResponseTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ResponseTimer.Tick
    'MessageBox.Show("No Respone Yet")
    LastCommand = LastCommand
End Sub
```

So it's asking my first command every 4 second until I get something in return, but when I start over with the second command the Timer does not tick.

I'm using .NET 4.0 and the {Windows.Forms.Timer}, I tried with Timers.Timer and did not work either I don't understand why it does not start again.

Comment: I've manage to make it work by using System.Timers.Timer I guess I did something wrong the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looked like System.Timers.Timer was the best options I managed to make the elapse event trigger every 4 second after I sent a command every time I do so.

Answer (score 0):

In property 'LastCommand' check value not equals lastCommandString and also if ResponseTimer isnot enabled, maybe it will help:

```
Public Property LastCommand() As String
    Get
        Return lastCommandString
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        if value = lastCommandString then exit property
        lastCommandString = value
        MainCOMSerialPort.Write(value)
        if Not ResponseTimer.Enabled Then ResponseTimer.Start()
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I've manage to make it work by using System.Timers.Timer I guess I did something wrong the first time I don't know.